# meson cant find a cross-compile library

Tags: c++, linux, cross-compiling, meson-build

I'm building my project using `meson`.

When building native - all is OK. `meson` is able to find all dependencies, and create the executable.

When using a `aarch` cross file - the dependency just doesn't work...

This is my `meson.build`:

```
# builds the project and copies all relevant data files
project(
  'demo',
  'cpp',
  default_options : [
    'cpp_std=c++20',
  ],
  version: run_command('cat', '.version', check: true).stdout().strip(),
)

################
# dependencies #
################
dependencies = [
  dependency('CLI11'),
  dependency('nlohmann_json'),
  dependency('spdlog'),
  meson.get_compiler('cpp').find_library('MY_LIB')
]

##############
# executable #
##############
executable(
  'demo',
  files('src'),
  dependencies : dependencies,
  install : true,
)
```

and this is my cross file (aarch64.ini):

```
; arm 64 bit little endian
[binaries]
cpp = 'aarch64-none-linux-gnu-g++'
strip = 'aarch64-none-linux-gnu-strip'
pkg-config = 'aarch64-none-linux-gnu-pkg-config'
```

and I compile using `meson setup --cross-file aarch64.ini aarch64`

I've installed the relevant cross compiler (g++-11), and all its relevant binaries + edited my PATH so it would include them.

This is my error:

```
meson.build:14:0: ERROR: C++ shared or static library 'MY_LIB' not found

A full log can be found at ... meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

I've tried putting the relevant lib file in

1. cwd
2. /usr/lib/
3. /usr/lib/arm/64/ (and edited the find_library function to include that dir)

I also tried copying it / linking it without the version (i.e. tried both MY_LIB.so.4.8.1 and MY_LIB.so)

Nothing works...

The lib I try to link against is in the correct format:

```
$ file MY_LIB.so.4.8.1 
MY_LIB.so.4.8.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=457ef064499398e8ffe4657e60fe44f30cb7db51, not stripped
```

What am I supposed to look for so I can solve this?

My thoughts:

1. maybe my definition (my cross file) doesn't match the lib I'm linking against? I've tried to verify it using `file` but maybe I'm wrong?
2. maybe the `none` in the compiler name is an issue (shouldn't it be just aarch-linux-gnu?)
3. maybe my pkg-config is bad somehow? (I don't have a aarch64...pkg-config. Is there one?)

Answer (score 1):

is there the symlink MY_LIB.so to  MY_LIB.so.4.8.1?
you can try also in this way to include the dependency:

```
myLibDep = declare_dependency(
    link_args : ['<my lib path>/MY_LIB.so'])
```

....

```
dependencies = [
  dependency('CLI11'),
  dependency('nlohmann_json'),
  dependency('spdlog'),
  myLibDep,
]
```